# How to make an object with the same behaviour than open() before with and for statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, contextmanager

I would like to create a class in Python that receive a filename, and return an object that can be handled by a context manager and iterable by a for-loop.

Basicly, the file will be parsed line by line (iterable). The class will split each line into a defined pattern and will return at each step of iteration a tuple of values.

I know that I need to implement `__iter__`, `__next__` methods to make it iterable but I do not clearly understand how to proceed. The file is one of my class attribute, and I want the iterator to yield parsed line at each iteration.

I also know that I need to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, but this also is a little bit fuzzy to me.

```
class myfile:
    def __init__(self,file,**kwargs):
        self._file = open(file,'r')

    def __del__(self):
        self._file.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        # Not sure what am I supposed to return here

    def __exit__(self):
        self._file.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        # What iterator must be returned

    def __next__(self):
        return parseLine(x)

    def parseLine(self,line):
        #Stuff:
        return *values
```

I am not looking for an out-of-the box code, rather I would like to understand what each of those magic methods exactly needs to properly works in order to get the desired behaviour.

**Update:**

I finally resolved to do it in the following way:

```
class myfile:
    def __init__(self,file,**kwargs):
        self._file = open(file,'r')

    def __del__(self):
        self._file.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._file.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        for fline in self._file:
            yield self.parseLine(fline)

    def parseLine(self,line):
        # Stuff
        return *values
```

It seems to have the behaviour I am looking for. It works when I perform:

```
with myfile(r'x.txt') as pf:
    for i in pf:
        print(i)
```

Is this a good way to achieve it? Is it pythonic enough?

Answer (score 1):

Just return `self` in both cases.

Your class is itself the iterator (since you are providing a `__next__` method), and if you don't have a special value for `__enter__` to return you generally just return `self`.

In fact, that's exactly what a file object does for both cases:

```
>>> fobj = open('/dev/null')
>>> fobj.__enter__() is fobj
True
>>> fobj.__iter__() is fobj
True
```

For `__iter__` you'd return a different object if you wanted to support independent iteration over the object; that new object would then return `self` for `__iter__` and provide the `__next__` method rather than this class.

For `__enter__` you'd return whatever was convenient for the user to bind to in a `with` statement. For example, some database connection objects return a new cursor object, so that you can do:

```
with conn as cursor:
    # handle a transaction, using the already produced cursor
```

Note that your updated version returns a *generator* from `__iter__`, which is a *new* iterator each time you call `iter(myfile('...'))`. These iterators are not really independent as `iter(fileobj)` will always return the file object itself, so iterating over one generator will affect the other generators as the file position advances.

Moreover, since file objects are their own iterator, you can use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) directly on a file object, but you cannot do the same on your object.

A better solution is to stick to returning `self` and make your `__next__` method do the parsing:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    return self.parseLine(next(self._file))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you check out if the update I have made is correct

Comment: @jlandercy: kind-of; your `__iter__` now returns a new generator (a type of iterator) each time it is called; this means you now can create separate iterators for the file object. In this case that's okay, as the file object itself still will only return `self`, and the independent iterators are not really independent.

Comment: @jlandercy: that is probably fine; but you could also use `def __next__(self): return self.parseLine(next(self._file))` instead of creating a generator.

Comment: @jlandercy: the downside of your approach is that `next(yourobject)` won't work, while `next(fileobj)` *does* work.